# PHP curl and Web Proxy...maybe

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a script which calls an external API using curl. This script worked perfectly when the website was on a dedicated server however I have had to move the server to a load balanced set up which sits behind a proxy and now for some reason I get

PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in...file name.

In Firebug it comes back as a 500 error if there is a result (formatted XML) otherwise it processes as normal.

I am running Zend CE 5.1.0 with only the default modules installed. Do I need to set something on the proxy or do I need to install additional modules to get this working.

If you need further information let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you defined your proxy in php?

Something like:

```
define('HTTP_PROXY_HOST', '192.168.100.100');
define('HTTP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
if (defined('HTTP_PROXY_HOST') && HTTP_PROXY_HOST != '') {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, HTTP_PROXY_HOST);
}
if (defined('HTTP_PROXY_PORT') && HTTP_PROXY_PORT != '') {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, HTTP_PROXY_PORT);
}
```

Comment: No I hadnt however I have added an entry into windows registry and the site loads perfectly except for the one curl command. I will try your suggestion

Comment: Now I get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Comment: Are you getting well formated XML back?
Maybe problem is on other side?

Comment: Yeah I am because I used the exact same script on a different server. If I change the server back to the original IP it works. Do you think I am missing a php module?

Comment: Printr whatever you getting back.

Comment: Actually your solution worked however I had to add it after all the other curl_setopt commands. Thank you so much.